# how to find two different files with find command

Tags: find

I stucked at one point where my script should find two different files. One of them time stamp is like `D210929` another one `20210929`. I have these two files:

```
HGIS4C.IOPZ.IP4.CCCP.D210929.S004596.IO99999.19992.1111.CCCP.IP9999
HGS4C.SCS.CCA1.TSILocationContactData20210929.zip
```

My question is that how can find these two files with `find` command? E.g.

```
find . -name "TBSI4C.[SCS]*.[D]${DATE}" | grep -c TBSI4C 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: current date: 20210929

Comment: Hi... you should add relevant answers to comments to the main question

Comment: The `find` command you've provided doesn't match either of the example files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a date on the form `YYYYMMDD` in the shell variable `date`, you can trim off the two first characters from that with `${date#??}`.

Now you can use `find` to search for regular files in or below the current directory whose names match either of the two patterns `*$date.zip` or `*.D${date#??}.*`.

```bsh
find . -type f \( -name "*$date.zip" -o -name "*.D${date#??}.*" \)
```

The above would find the two files (or, it would find at least those two files). Call a utility via the `-exec` option of `find` if you want to do something to the files. Since you don't say how you plan to use the files, it's impossible to give practical examples here.

Comment: Trim off the two characters from `date` was perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple `-name PATTERN` parameters, like so

```
find . -name PATTERN1 -o -name PATTERN2
```